# How to display NIFTI image that is read using vtkNIFTIImageReader with VTK

Tags: vtk, nifti

I can display sliced images using vtkNIFTIImageReader with the following code : https://github.com/dgobbi/vtk-dicom/blob/master/Examples/TestNIFTIDisplay.cxx

However, when I try to render the NIFTI file as a 3D object, it always comes up empty. How can I display NIFTI objects in VTK

```
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkNIFTIImageReader> reader =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkNIFTIImageReader>::New();

   reader->SetFileName (filename); 
   reader->Update();

   vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
   mapper->SetInputConnection(reader->GetOutputPort());

   vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> actor =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
   actor->SetMapper(mapper);

   vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
   vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
   renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);

   vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> renderWindowInteractor =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
   renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);
   renderer->AddActor(actor);

   renderWindow->Render();
   renderWindowInteractor->Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the correct visualization for an image (structured data),  not a mesh.

You can try to run a marching cube algorithm in order to obtain a mesh and then use a polydata mapper, or use something derived from vtkvolumemapper.